# Getting a blank cell or daysif in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Trying to get days on a job on my spreadsheet but leave blank if no date entered. Something like =IF(ISBLANK(L10),"", =DATEDIF(L10-,N10, "d"). There is a start date a projected end date but I want to know how many days since the start of the job regardless of the end date and leaving blank if no start date entered.

L10 = start date
N10 = current date

[excel sheet showing issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjT9U.png)

Answer (score 2):

You are close, but you cannot have the equal sign twice in a formula. And the datedif formula is slightly off.

Should be:

```
    =IF(ISBLANK(A2),"",DATEDIF(A2,C2,"d"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been trying not to ask for help but I just could not get this to work.